# Need to submit choice ID as part of a form, how can I do this?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, registration

I need to submit the `Choice_ID` in the form below to my database as it is used in another function. How would I pass this to the PHP code that handles the user registration? The error messages I am getting are:

`Notice: Undefined index: Choice_ID in /Users/philip/sites/feedmefit/Assets/register.php on line 16`

`Notice: Undefined index: Choice_ID in /Users/philip/sites/feedmefit/Assets/register.php on line 17`

HTML code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Personal Details</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="Assets/register.php" method="post">
                    <label>Forename:</label><br><input type="text" id="f" name="Forename" placeholder="Forename" required><br/>
                    <label>Surname:</label><br><input type="text" id="s" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" required><br/>
                    <label>House Number:</label><br><input type="text" id="h" name="House_No" placeholder="House Number" required><br/>
                    <label>Street Name:</label><br><input type="text" id="sn" name="Street_Name" placeholder="Street Name" required><br/>
                    <label>City:</label><br><input type="text" id="c" name="City" placeholder="Town/City" required><br/>
                    <label>Postcode:</label><br><input type="text" id="p" name="Postcode" placeholder="Postcode" required><br/>
                    <label>Username:</label><br><input type="text" id="u" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required><br/>
                    <label>Password:</label><br><input type="text" id="pd" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required><br/>
                    <label>Email:</label><br><input type="text" id="e" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required><br/>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Questionnaire</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT Question_ID, Question FROM Questions;";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($resultCheck > 0):
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                    $questionid = (int)$row['Question_ID'];
                    echo '<label>'.$row['Question'].'</label><input type="hidden" value="'.$row['Question_ID'].'">';

                    $query = "SELECT Choice_ID, Choice FROM Choices WHERE Question_ID = '$questionid';";
                    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    $resultsCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);
                    if($resultsCheck > 0):
                        $string = '<br><select id="choice">';
                        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)):
                            $string .= '<option value="'.$rows['Choice_ID'].'">'.$rows['Choice'].'</option>';
                    endwhile;
                    $string .= '</select><br>';
                    echo $string;
                endif;
            endwhile;
        endif;
        ?>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the PHP that handles the registration:

```
<?php
session_start();
//Connect to DB
include 'DBConnection.php';

$Forename = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Forename']);
$Surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Surname']);
$House_No = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['House_No']);
$Street_Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Street_Name']);
$City = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['City']);
$Postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Postcode']);
$Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Username']);
$Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Password']);
$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Email']);

$choice = $_POST['Choice_ID'];
print_r($_POST['Choice_ID']);
exit();

$sql = "INSERT INTO Customers (Forename, Surname, House_No, Street_Name, City, Postcode, Username, Password, Email) 
VALUES ('$Forename', '$Surname', '$House_No', '$Street_Name', '$City', '$Postcode', '$Username', '$Password', '$Email')";
$query = "INSERT INTO Results (Result_ID, Cust_ID, Choice_ID) 
VALUES(,,'$choice')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$results = $conn->query($query);

header("Location: ../index.php");
```

Comment: `<select id="choice">` to `<select id="choice" name="Choice_ID">`? Also your code is wide open to sql injection attacks. Try using prepared statements.

Comment: check $choice  before insert like if(isset($choice )) { insert }

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou I am going to fix it so it's protected against injection attacks. I just need it work first

Comment: Did you change what i said and it still not works?

Comment: I have changed it and it works but I am only getting one choice ID, not 4

Comment: Well `<select>` only sends one choise which by default is the first one. You either have to use `<select multiple>` or checkboxes if you want to send more than one.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou For each question, there are 2 choices. The user must only be able to select one choice for each question. However, when I submit the form, only one choice is submitted out of the 4 that should be submitted if this makes sense

Comment: OK now i got you. You should then use either the question_ID or an iterator eg. `$i` in the name field `<select id="choice" name="Choice_ID'.$i.'">` or `<select id="choice" name="Choice_ID'.$row["Question_ID"].'">`

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou I will try this, although, how can I get `$i` to increment the `Choice_ID` if the `<select>` tags are outside the while loop that gets the choices?

Comment: I'll post an answer since it is too much to say in comments

Comment: @DimitrisFillippou Ok I tried that and it works, however, I am getting an undefined variable error as `$i` hasn't been defined yet where you told me to insert it

Comment: Please see about sql injection and prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given no name to you `<select>` inputs.
You have to change `<select id="choice">` to `<select id="choice" name="Choice_ID'.$i.'">`

Now you have to change add the following code to increse `$i` for every question.

```
$sql = "SELECT Question_ID, Question FROM Questions;";
```

to

```
$i=0;
$sql = "SELECT Question_ID, Question FROM Questions;";
```

and

```
                endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
```

to

```
                endif;
                $i++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
```

Now on your registration  php you have to read `$choice0 = $_POST['Choice_ID0'];` `$choice1 = $_POST['Choice_ID10'];` etc and make different insert queries for each of them.

Also you code is wide open to SQL Injection attacks. `mysqli_real_escape_string` does not fully protect you, you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)